I can't find /usr/local/cuda-<x>.<y>/gds/samples after I install cuda tookit and driver
I want to use GPUDirect Storage. I follow the instructions in https://docs.nvidia.com/gpudirect-storage/troubleshooting-guide/index.html#mofed-req-install to install it. The install details are as follow:

I firstly install cuda tookit and driver from here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_network.

Then, According to https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect-storage , GDS should be now part of CUDA. But when I have a look in gds file to check whether the gds file is right ,  I found:
(base) no@ho-4:/usr/local/cuda-12.6/gds$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10756  Aug 22 13:36 cufile.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14290  Aug 22 13:36 README
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096  Sep 23 15:59 tools

The right example one that nvidia docs give is:
$ ls -lh /usr/local/cuda-X.Y/gds/
total 20K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.4K Mar 15 13:01 README
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar 19 12:29 samples
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K mar 19 10:28 tools



I can't find samples folders and find another unknown file cufile.json. Samples folder should contain example usage program to test the gds functionality. It is upset that I don't have it. Could someone please help me to have my sample folder back ??o_o
By the way, I install MLNX_OFED because I need NVME support. when I installed MLNX_OFED using instructions in https://docs.nvidia.com/gpudirect-storage/troubleshooting-guide/index.html#mofed-req-install , I found that:
(base) no@ho-4::/usr/local/cuda-12.6/gds/tools$ ./gdscheck.py -v
warn: error opening log file: Permission denied, logging will be disabled
 GDS release version: 1.11.1.6
 nvidia_fs not loaded, operating on compatible mode. libcufile version: 2.12
 Platform: x86_64

nvidia_fs module is not loaded. I install it using:
sudo apt install nvidia-fs

But it seems that it is not a related new version of nvidia_fs. Could someone also tell me how can I download related new version of nvidia_fs?o_o

Since StackOverflow is focused on Questions/Answers directly related to coding issues, I would encourage you to post your question over at AskUbuntu.
